# I have always thought that painting was pretty bad. Why can he use 'always' in present perfect tense？

Tags: grammar, present-perfect, adverbs

> I have always thought that painting was pretty bad.

Why can he use 'always' in  present perfect tense？ I think 'always' was used only in present tense.

Comment: Why would you think he can't use "always".  Some more details please.

Comment: @JamesK  I think 'always' was used in  present tense.

Comment: I always used to think that, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Always*** can be used in lots of tenses. In fact, I'm struggling to think of any tense that can't take it. I'm not sure there's any combination of tense, mood, aspect etc that can't take the adverb *always*. One might say that you can always use *always*.

The meaning may be subtly different for the different cases, of course.

> **I have always** loved hot dogs.

Literally, there is no point in time, up to and including now, that I did not love hotdogs.

> **I had always** thought that professional wrestling wasn't scripted.

This can mean either of two things:

1. There is no point in time, up to and including the reference time of the sentence, that I didn't think professional wrestling wasn't scripted.
2. There is some point in the past, probably recent, at which I stopped thinking that professional wrestling wasn't scripted; at every time before that, I thought professional wrestling wasn't scripted.

> **I always** confuse Belgium and the Netherlands

Literally stating that I can never remember which is which of those two countries. Usually used figuratively to mean that I get them confused often.

> **I was always** the bottom of my class in school

Describing something that was generally and consistently true in the past.

> **I will always** stand by you

Literally a statement that I will continue to stand by you (which is to say support you); generally used as a way of expressing a promise.

> I thought that **I would always** be a failure

Expressing a belief about the future in the past, that I once thought that I would be a failure at every point of time in the future.

Hopefully, that helps illustrate things for you.

Answer (score 1):

I have always thought that painting was pretty bad.

You can use always, never, ever, and a few others adverbs in most tenses.

- I always get to work on time.
- I have always gotten to work on time recently.
- I always got to work on time in the past.
- I'm always getting to work late these days.
- Last year, he always went to work on the bus.

The use of the adverbs is not related to the tense necessarily. These are adverbs of frequency (often, never, (ever: special case), always, usually, frequently,etc.).

With **ever**, generally, one does use PP or some other tense but not the present simple: Have you ever been to Hong Kong?